# JDownloader Remote how to detect ip adress Android

Tags: android, ip, broadcast, jdownloader

I'm developing android app for JDownloader. I need to connect to it on local subnet, but ofcourse I need to know computers IP. Does JDdownloader Remote plugin send some kind of broadcast message or only way how to set ip is user input? I did not find anything on that topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it my way. When you call /get/version on right ip and port then jdownloader returns "JDownloader" string. So I request this url for all ips for device's subnet and check if response contains that string.